# Как получить доступ к аргументу функции, если есть переменная с таким же названием?

Tags: swift

У меня есть такая функция:

```
let string = "global"

func myFunction(string: String)
{
   let string = "string"
   print("my string \(string)")
}
```

Как, к примеру, распечатать переменную из аргумента функции, а не ту, которая объявлена в функции?

Comment: И резонный вопрос - а на фига так делать вообще?

Comment: Свит такое разрешает, что ли???

Comment: Есть у меня привычка из java называть одинаково поля класса и переменные в геттерах и сеттерах. 'public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }' - вот так к примеру. Здесь я могу обратиться к полю в классе через this. А как я в Swift могу обратиться к глобальной переменной, если в функции уже существует переменная с таким же именем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если имя аргумента и переменной совпадают, то в теле функции всегда будет использовано значение переменной, а не аргумента, и такое поведение также находит свое отражение в операциях с опционалами (более распространенный вариант совпадения имен)

```
func myFunction2(string: String?)
{
    if let string = string {
        print("my string \(string)")
    }
}
```

Вы также можете сделать следующее:

```
func myFunction(string: String)
{
   let string = string
   print("my string \(string)")
}
```

**Дополнение**

Для обращения к глобальной переменной можно использовать `self.string`

```
let string = "global"

func myFunction(string: String)
{
   let string = "string"
   print("my string \(self.string)")
}
```

Comment: То есть получается, что в моем коде по сути одна переменная, которой таким образом просто присваивается другое значение?

Comment: Тогда еще такой вопрос (я изменил свой код): как мне внутри функции получить доступ к переменной со значением "global" ? Это вообще возможно?

Comment: @alexbayker см дополнение к ответу